# Exclude certain children when selecting objects based on class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function, that finds input fields in code block:

```
$('.files-block').each(function(n, element) {
// some code that finds imput fields
});
```

Problem is that I need to exclude input fields in div .second-files-block.

I tried using:

```
$('.files-block').children().not('.second-files-block')

$('.files-block:not(.second-files-block)')

$('.files-block').not('.second-files-block')
```

nothing really works... What is correct way to do it?

Example code

```
<div id="filesBlock">
    <div class="files-block" id="files-block1">
        <input class="files" type="text" id="files" />
        <div id="filesSecondBlock">
            <div class="files-second-block" id="files-second-block1">
                <input class="files" type="text" id="files" /><!-- exclude this -->
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML structure please

Comment: I think you need `$('.files-block :not(.second-files-block)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the jQuery child selector `>`

```
$(".files-block > input")
```

That will select only `inputs` that are direct children of `.files-block`.

This JSFiddle makes the target `input` red: http://jsfiddle.net/Px7Pw/

Comment: Thank you, this was most clean way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use as below

```
 $('div[class="second-files-block"] :input[class="files-block"])
```

It will search only those input having class `files-block`, those belongs to div with class `second-files-block`